# Calculate a two wheeled robot wheels rotation velocity for different movement

Tags: classical-mechanics, electric-circuits, velocity, rotation, geometry

Consider the following situation. I have a two-wheeled robot like that 
[image: two wheeles robot]

I have required information: size of a robot, radius of wheels and so on.

Also I have an object that the robot should pass around.

I know its absolute position and the robots position as well.

I need to calculate the wheels' velocity to follow a circle path around an object.

Velocity is an abstract value in this case - I need to find just a relation between provided properties.

For example if I set velocity of the right motor to 4 and the left motor to the -4 it will rotate around its own axis (approx.). If I set the left to 0 and the right one to 4 it will move anti-clockwise.

Comment: Hawe a look at this article: http://rossum.sourceforge.net/papers/DiffSteer/. With those formulas it should be possible to figure out how to make a certain circle.

Comment: Discussed in the hbar chat room [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41099687#41099687).